# parsing multiple urls from the form

Tags: php, parsing, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make a script, which search the list of urls given in the form for the email adresses. Could anyone advice me how to do it? Is there some alternative to cURL?
I tried to make it with file_get_contents, but the script analyze only the last url given in the form: when I enter for example two urls to the form, the first "print_r("show current_url:". $current_url); is empty and for the second it shows the page(url) content(without pictures).

I asked on different forums, but received no answer. Will really appraciate your help.

Thank you

```
$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']); 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'urls');  

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'B&#322;&#261;d: ';
    exit;
}


for ($i=0; $i<count($urls); $i++){

print_r("show link:". $urls[$i]."<br>");

$current_url = file_get_contents($urls[$i]);
print_r("show current_url:". $current_url); 


    preg_match( "/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $current_url, $email);//email


    print_r ("show email:".$email[0]);


    $query = "INSERT INTO urle set adres = '$email[0]' "; 

    $result = $db->query($query);




}

if ($query) {
    echo $db->affected_rows ."pozycji dodano.";
} else {
    echo mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error() .   "Wyst&#261;pi&#322; b&#322;&#261;d przy dodawaniu urli  ";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

---

EDIT:
I have tried with curl. var_dump($email); shows: array(0) { }
The script displays now all of the urls given in the form in the browser, but preg_match doesn't work, so it doesn't extract email adresses.

```
<?php


$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']); 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'linki');  

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Błąd: ';
    exit;
}


for ($i=0; $i<count($urls); $i++){

    $url = $urls[$i];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match( "/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $output, $email);//email
var_dump($email);

    $query = "INSERT INTO urle set adres = '$email[0]' "; 
    $result = $db->query($query);


curl_close($ch);



}//

if ($result) {
    echo $db->affected_rows ."pozycji dodano.";
} else {
    echo mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error() .   "Wystąpił błąd przy dodawaniu urli  ";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've fixed it!!!:)

Here is the code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($linki); $i++){

$url = $linki[$i];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result =curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match("/[-a-z0-9\._]+@[-a-z0-9\._]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/", $result, $email);//email
print_r($email);

    $zapytanie = "INSERT INTO urle set adres = '$email[0]' "; 
    $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);





}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some alternative to cURL?

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), which doesn't give you any error messages (unless error_reporting is raised), and which is often blocked unless `ini_set("user_agent", ...)` was set.

Alternatively [`HttpRequest`](http://php.net/HttpRequest) on newer PHP installations.

Still [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) is not difficult to use. The manual is full of examples.

> the first "print_r("show current_url:". $current_url); is empty

Nobody can tell. It's your duty to debug that (especially since you haven't mentioned the affected url in your question). Use curl or httprequest.

Comment: I've edited my post and change the script to curl. The current problem is descriped above. I am counting on your help

Comment: You need CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER. Option CURLOPT_URL is pointless.